# Given a set of types, how can I check if every type has a unique field `k`?

Tags: typescript

How can I implement a type `UniqueK<T>` type which can tell me whether two or more of the types in `T` have a key `k` with the same value?

`T` can be an union type (`{k:number}`), a tuple (`{k:number}[]`) or whatever else is comfortable to work with.

```js
type UniqueK<T extends ...> = ... ? true : false;

// it should behave this way:
UniqueK<[{k:1}, {k:2}]>         = true
UniqueK<[{k:7}, {k:42}, {k:0}]> = true
UniqueK<[{k:1}, {k:1}]>         = false // since k:1 is repeated
UniqueK<[{k:7}, {k:42}, {k:7}]> = false // since k:7 is repeated
```

I'm only concerned with types that are literal numbers. I don't care about cases where some of the types are something else (e.g. `number`, `any`, `7|8`). Ideally I would want `UniqueK` to evaluate to `false` if any non-literal-number is used, but this is not a strong requirement.

Comment: • Could you [edit] so this isn't mostly pseudocode? It would help if everything except for the part you don't know how to write could be pasted into an IDE and worked on directly without needing to fix typos. In other words, could you provide a [mre]? • What about `UniqueK<[{k: number}, {k: 2}]>` or `UniqueK<[{k: 0 | 1}, {k: 1 | 2}]>`? Does "unique" mean "no overlap" or does it mean "not identical"?

Comment: Please see prev comment. Assuming it means "no overlap" then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WooVpW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (after you make the requested [edit]s or you let me make them). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: The values of `k` I care about are all literal numbers, so I don't really care about other types (unions, `number`, `any` etc): both the version with and without overlap would work.

Comment: I edited the function. I have no idea how to edit it so that it's less pseudocode. If you know how, feel free to suggest an edit!

Comment: Oh, and the approach you suggested seems good! Send it as a response and I'll accept it.